# SKAction is not pausing when app goes to background

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, skaction

I am keeping time in my game by having the scene run an `SKAction`:

```
let action = SKAction.waitForDuration(1)
let timeRun = SKAction.runBlock({
        self.gameTime += 1.0
})
self.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(SKAction.sequence([action, timeRun])))
```

My understanding is `SKScene`'s default behavior is to pause when the app goes goes into the background.  This appears to be the case: when the app is activated again, everything looks as before and scene immediately resumes.  But the game time jumps by however long the game was in the background, so it appears the timer action never stopped running.  I don't understand - if the scene was paused, then aren't all the actions the scene is running also paused?

Either an explanation or suggestion of a better method would be welcome.

Comment: This should work on iOS8. Not sure how its meant to be on iOS9. Which iOS do you have installed on testing device ?

Comment: The device is iOS9, but without knowing the particulars of the upgrade, I would be surprised to learn that would affect this kind of behavior.